# Unable to use jquery function in ember js

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I included this code in index.ejs file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function()
    {
       $('#username').glDatePicker();
    });
</script>
```

but this jquery code is working only for the ids on the first landing page(login in this case) , for rest of the pages it is not working. Kindly suggest how to make it work for all the ids in other pages also.

Comment: Are you asking how to change the selector to match other elements?

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery load event, is just trigered one time, when the window load, and when it happens, some templates aren't present in the dom, because ember save this templates, and just append in the dom when you make a transition to the respective route.

Since your `glDatePicker` is to customize the input tag, in other words a custom component. I recommend you to create your own view class. This is easy with ember:

```
App.DatePickerView = Ember.TextField.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().glDatePicker();
    }
});
```

And in your template you can use:

```
{{view App.DatePickerView valueBinding=date}}
```

So each new `DatePickerView` created will use the jquery plugin.

If you want more syntactic sugar, you can use the `Ember.Handlebars.helper`:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('date-picker', App.DatePickerView);
```

So in your templates you can use just:

```
{{date-picker value=date}}
```

This is a fiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/3saXK/

I hope it helps